# Navigation Menu border bottom line expand from middle

Tags: html, css, sass

Here I have a navigation menu

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a><div></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">PAGE</a><div></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a><div></div></li>
  <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a><div></div></li>
</ul>
```

I made the border bottom line appears on hover and in active menu. But the question is how to make the animation effect.

**SCSS**

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  li {
    float: left;
    &:hover a {
      cursor: pointer;
      color: blue;
    }
    &:hover div,
    &.router-link-active div {
      border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
      border-width: thin;
      margin-left: 15%;
      margin-right: 15%;
    }
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: grey;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aKQMmq) link. Need the animation like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/emNjGo). But without deleting the div element next to anchor tag.

Comment: why you don't take the good code and edit it?

Comment: I need the border bottom line with particular length. In the good code the length occupies the full area covered by parent element.

Comment: `In the good code the length occupies the full area` --> you can easily change it, in the code there is `width:100%` simply make it lower

Comment: make div position absolute and width auto. play with left and right property. normlly left and right 100% and on hover left and right 0 and it's done

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided uses [CSS pseudo classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) for the border-like effect.

**HTML**

```
   <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav_item">Home</li>
        <li class="nav_item">About</li>
        <li class="nav_item">Contact</li>
        <li class="nav_item">help</li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
        .nav{
            list-style: none;
            position:fixed;
        }
        .nav_item{
            display:inline-block;
            padding:10px;
            font-size:25px;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .nav_item:after{
            content:'';
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            height: 3px;
            width: 0px;
            background: transparent;
            transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
        }
        .nav_item:hover:after{
            width:100%; /*change the width of the border like element*/
            background:red;
        }
```

In case you want to change the width of the pseudo class, change the width of `.nav_item:hover:after` in the CSS

**Example:**

```
.nav_item:hover:after{
       width:50%;
       background:red 
 }
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjoerz56/2/

Comment: it's not pseudo classe but pseudo element